# Python Excel Calculations

Tags: python, pandas, operating-system, openpyxl, data-manipulation

I am not getting correct calculations for 3 columns I am trying to write on a data sheet for specific date and time in time series data. I want to calculate difference between various times and the closing price time. I am having problem for some reason I can't get correct output for the calculations.

This is the output from this code.

```
import pandas as pd
import os
import numpy as np
from openpyxl import Workbook

# Read the data into a Pandas DataFrame
directory_path = "C:/Users/bean/Desktop/_L"
os.chdir(directory_path)
book = Workbook()
book.remove(book.active)  # remove the first sheet

for file in os.listdir(directory_path):
    if file.endswith(".csv"):
        file_path = os.path.join(directory_path, file)
        df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
        # Create a new DataFrame for each file
        df_diff = df[['Date', 'CET', 'NA', 'UTC', 'Name', 'BOLLBU', 'BOLLBM', 'BOLLBL',
                      'VWAP', 'VWAPSD1U', 'VWAPSD1L', 'VWAPSD2U', 'VWAPSD2L', 'ATR', 'ATRMA']]

        df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
        df['CET'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
        df['UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
        df['NA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
        df_diff['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
        df_diff['CET'] = pd.to_datetime(df['CET'])
        df_diff['UTC'] = pd.to_datetime(df['UTC'])
        df_diff['NA'] = pd.to_datetime(df['NA'])
        df_diff['Open'] = df['Open']
        df_diff['High'] = df['High']
        df_diff['Low'] = df['Low']
        df_diff['Close'] = df['Close']
        # Calculate the differences and add them as new columns
        df_diff['Open Diff'] = (df['Open'].shift(-1) -
                                df['Open']) / df['Open'] * 100
        df_diff['High Diff'] = (df['High'].shift(-1) -
                                df['High']) / df['High'] * 100
        df_diff['Low Diff'] = (df['Low'].shift(-1) -
                               df['Low']) / df['Low'] * 100
        df_diff['Close Diff'] = (
            df['Close'].shift(-1) - df['Close']) / df['Close'] * 100

        df_1635 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 16) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 35)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1625 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 16) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 25)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1620 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 16) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 20)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1615 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 16) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 15)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1610 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 16) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 10)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1605 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 16) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 5)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1600 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 16) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 0)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1545 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 15) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 45)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1530 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 15) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 30)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1500 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 15) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 0)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1445 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 14) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 45)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1430 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 14) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 30)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1400 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 14) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 0)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1330 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 13) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 30)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1300 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 13) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 0)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_1230 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 12) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 30)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_0800 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 8) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 0)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)

        # Calculate difference between Close price of df_1635 and other DataFrames
        df_diff_1635_1625 = df_1635['Close'] - df_1625['Close']
        df_diff_1635_1620 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1620['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1615 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1615['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1610 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1610['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1605 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1605['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1600 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1600['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1545 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1545['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1530 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1530['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1500 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1500['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1445 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1445['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1430 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1430['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1400 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1400['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1330 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1330['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1300 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1300['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_1230 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1230['Close'])
        df_diff_1635_0800 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_0800['Close'])
        print(df_diff_1635_1625)

        # Add Difference, Percent_Diff, and U/D columns to each DataFrame
        df_1635['Difference'] = df_1635['Close'].subtract(
            df_1635['Close'].shift())
        df_1635['Percent_Diff'] = (df_1635['Difference'] /
                                   df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1635['U/D'] = np.where(df_1635['Difference'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1625['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1625
        df_1625['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1625 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1625['U/D'] = np.where(df_1625['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')
        print(df_1625.dtypes)

        df_1620['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1620
        df_1620['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1620 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1620['U/D'] = np.where(df_1620['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1615['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1615
        df_1615['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1615 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1615['U/D'] = np.where(df_1615['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1610['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1610
        df_1610['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1610 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1610['U/D'] = np.where(df_1610['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1605['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1605
        df_1605['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1605 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1605['U/D'] = np.where(df_1605['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1600['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1600
        df_1600['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1600 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1600['U/D'] = np.where(df_1600['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1545['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1545
        df_1545['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1545 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1545['U/D'] = np.where(df_1545['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1530['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1530 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1530['U/D'] = np.where(df_1530['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1500['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1500
        df_1500['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1500 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1500['U/D'] = np.where(df_1500['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1445['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1445
        df_1445['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1445 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1445['U/D'] = np.where(df_1445['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1430['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1430
        df_1430['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1430 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1430['U/D'] = np.where(df_1430['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1400['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1400
        df_1400['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1400 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1400['U/D'] = np.where(df_1400['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1330['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1330
        df_1330['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1330 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1330['U/D'] = np.where(df_1330['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1300['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1300
        df_1300['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1300 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1300['U/D'] = np.where(df_1300['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_1230['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_1230
        df_1230['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_1230 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_1230['U/D'] = np.where(df_1230['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_0800['Difference'] = df_diff_1635_0800
        df_0800['Percent_Diff'] = (df_diff_1635_0800 / df_1635['Close']) * 100
        df_0800['U/D'] = np.where(df_0800['Percent_Diff'] > 0, 'U', 'D')

        df_25 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 16) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 25)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_35 = df[(df['Date'].dt.hour == 16) & (
            df['Date'].dt.minute == 35)].sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        # Concat all results for each time into this sheet.
        df_35 = df_35[['Date', 'CET', 'NA', 'UTC', 'Name', 'Open', 'Open Diff', 'High', 'High Diff', 'Low', 'Low Diff',
                       'Close', 'Close Diff', 'BOLLBU', 'BOLLBM', 'BOLLBL', 'VWAP', 'VWAPSD1U', 'VWAPSD1L', 'VWAPSD2U',
                       'VWAPSD2L', 'ATR', 'ATRMA']]

        df_diff = df_diff.sort_values(by='Date', ascending=False)
        df_diff = df_diff[['Date', 'CET', 'NA', 'UTC', 'Name', 'Open', 'Open Diff', 'High', 'High Diff', 'Low', 'Low Diff',
                           'Close', 'Close Diff', 'BOLLBU', 'BOLLBM', 'BOLLBL', 'VWAP', 'VWAPSD1U', 'VWAPSD1L', 'VWAPSD2U',
                           'VWAPSD2L', 'ATR', 'ATRMA']]

        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
            f'{file.split(".")[0]}.xlsx', engine='openpyxl')

        df_diff.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='df_diff', index=False, startrow=0)
        df_35.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet_35min', index=False)

        dataframes = [df_1625, df_1620, df_1615, df_1610, df_1605, df_1600, df_1545,
                      df_1530, df_1500, df_1445, df_1430, df_1400, df_1330, df_1300, df_1230, df_0800]

        for i, df in enumerate(dataframes):
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=f"df_{i}", index=False)

        writer.save()
```

Essentially, the calculations under the for loop and for df_35 are not coming out properly correctly? How am I doing the operations wrong? The date is datetime but I am accessing column in that specific time value so I don't understand why it doesn't work. I tried various ways here are a few calculation methods I tried that were still wrong,

Neither of these work

```
df_diff_1635_1625 = df_1635['Close'] - df_1625['Close']
        df_diff_1635_1620 = df_1635['Close'].subtract(df_1620['Close'])
```

all my columns are mostly float64 including close ones except date which is datetime. i check and print the calculation i get nan  values so its clearly not processing it.
`

Comment: Your code is really long. Can you use print(df_xxx) and find the error that way?

Comment: I KNOW I WANTED TO PUT IT FOR CONTEXT, IM ONLY GETTING THE ISSUE ON THE CALCULATIONS FOR THE 2OF3 COLUMNS I WANT DIFFERENCE, DIFERENCE%,

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: df_1635 = df_1635.reindex(
            df_1625.index, method='ffill', fill_value=np.nan) reindexing fixed the error not being able to do calculations

Comment: i dud that thank you good i dea.  I COME TO THE CONCLUSION THE PROBLEM IS THE ROW SIZE FOR ALL FILES MAY BE SLIGHTLY DIFFERENT AND WONT DO CALCULATIONS PROPERLY BECAUSE OF THAT.